# Relation between object

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, relation, imperative

For a few weeks I’ve been thinking about relation between objects – not especially OOP’s objects. For instance in **C++**, we’re used to representing that by layering pointers or container of pointers in the structure that needs an access to the other object. If an object `A` needs to have an access to `B`, it’s not uncommon to find a `B *pB` in `A`.

But I’m not a **C++** programmer anymore, I write programs using functional languages, and more especially in **Haskell**, which is a pure functional language. It’s possible to use pointers, references or that kind of stuff, but I feel strange with that, like “doing it the non-Haskell way”.

Then I thought a bit deeper about all that relation stuff and came to the point:

> *“Why do we even represent such relation by layering?*

I read some folks already thought about that ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify)). In my point of view, representing relations through explicit graphes is way better since it enables us to focus on the *core* of our type, and express relations later are through combinators (a bit like SQL does).

By *core* I mean that when we define `A`, we expect to define what `A` is *made of*, not what it *depends on*. For instance, in a video game, if we have a type `Character`, it’s legit to talk about `Trait`, `Skill` or that kind of stuff, but is it if we talk about `Weapon` or `Items`? I’m not so sure anymore. Then:

```
data Character = {
    chSkills :: [Skill]
  , chTraits :: [Traits]
  , chName   :: String
  , chWeapon :: IORef Weapon -- or STRef, or whatever
  , chItems  :: IORef [Item] -- ditto
  }
```

sounds really wrong in term of design to me. I’d rather prefer something like:

```
data Character = {
    chSkills :: [Skill]
  , chTraits :: [Traits]
  , chName   :: String
  }

-- link our character to a Weapon using a Graph Character Weapon
-- link our character to Items using a Graph Character [Item] or that kind of stuff
```

Furthermore, when a day comes to add new features, we can just create new types, new graphs and link. In the first design, we’d have to break the `Character` type, or use some kind of
work around to extend it.

What do you think about that idea? What do you think is best to deal with that kind of issues in **Haskell**, a pure functional language?

Comment: This is a good question and I would love to see it answered. However as it currently stands, it is not a good fit for StackOverflow. Questions on SO should be answerable and not primarily opinion-based. I believe lots of people will have lots of different answers for this question, none of which will be definitive enough to be acceptable.

Comment: I’m not here for a closed answer, but several answers :) Why do you think it’s unanswered?

Comment: @phaazon, you should read the help section. This may be better off on programmers? Not sure.. The problem is, your question will require very opinion based answers.

Comment: @phaazon Questions on this site should have a closed answer. Maybe try  http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Ok, I’m gonna move the post then.

Comment: Post here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241315/relation-between-objects

Thank you.